# Change text of listview in onItemClick (listview is filled by a string-array/arrayAdapter)

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to change the text in my listview.
In my onCreate I fill my listview and setting an OnItemClicklistener:

onCreate:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, trainingstage);

setListAdapter(adapter);

ListView listView = getListView();

listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

onItemClick:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

    switch (position) {

    case 0:

        tv.setText("Hello");

        IF I CLICK TEXT SHOULD CHANGE!
        break;
```

That works fine, but if I restart the activity the old text is back. I want to change the text forever, if I click on the listitem!

Comment: You need to change the underlying dataset. This means that you need to change the value in `trainingstage`.

Comment: How can I handle this?

Comment: Wait...is your string array coming from your xml resource file?

Comment: public String[] trainingstage = {"Anfänger",
         "Anfänger 2",
         "Amateur",
         "Amateur 2",
         "GET PRO! Halb-Profi",
         "GET PRO! Halb-Profi 2",
         "GET PRO! Profi",
         "GET PRO! Profi 2",
               };

Comment: thats my string-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by two options:

**Easier way**
Change `text` in `trainingstage` and set string array to STATIC!

**Better way**
If you want to save the text after click, you need some kind of database to store the change. Either use `sqlite` if you want to save different `text`. If number of `text` is fixed, better to use `SharedPreferences`. You would also need to restore the `text` from here to set the `TextView` on `Activity` start.

Answer (score 0):

ListViews as the name implies is the VIEW where data is presented to users. You use your ArrayAdapter to populate the ListView from your DATA. The DATA in this example is your trainingstage String list.

This is a good data separation technique used all over Android. If you just change the textview anything else that uses that data wont be updated, you have only updated the view. What you need to do is actually update the DATA layer(trainingstage) which in turn will be passed to the adapter then rendered by the list view.

Without knowing exactly where and how you get trainingstage data it's hard to give you a suggestion on how to do that but a simple example would be:

in onItemClick
trainingstage.get(position) = "My New String";
parent.notifyDatasetChanged();

This probably won't persist when you restart your activity. You will need to do additional steps to save the STATE of your DATA. Aashish talks briefly about that in an above post.